# check if any duplicate words exist in a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Using regex in javascript, how to check for the condition when duplicate words are present in a string?
The words could be located any where in the string:

Given: "but boys run fast boys are strong" or
"boys boys"

expected result: true, since there are 2 repeats of the word "boys"

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to find any tool _less suitable_ for the task than regex.

Comment: Does it have to be made with regex?

Comment: No, but regex gives a shorter / elegant and hopefully faster code.

Comment: _"expected result: true"_ Is requirement of Question to return a  `Boolean` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\b` matches word boundaries
`\w+` will match 1 or more word characters
`( ... )` creates a group for matches
`\1` will match the contents of matching group #1.

Putting this together, you want a regex containing `\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b`

Plus appropriate backslash quoting, etc.

---

@guest27134 pointed out the above is not the complete solution, since the OP wanted `true`/`false`, not just the regex:

```
var result = a_string.match(/\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b/g) !== null
```

---

Or, even shorter, as suggested by O.P.:

```
var result = /\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b/g.test(myStr)
```

Comment: "boy boy".match(/\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b/g) will not return true when it is expected to do so.

Comment: `.match(/.../)` does not return `true` ... it returns an array of the matches

Comment: @AJNeufeld Not certain how current Answer resolves original Question _"expected result: true, since there are 2 repeats of the word "boys""_?

Comment: @guest271314 `"boy boy".match(/\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b/g) !== null` would be the complete solution.

Comment: or `/\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b/g.test(myStr)`

Comment: You can add `.*` at the beginning to match other words that are not necessarily the first one. `.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b`

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that spaces are there after each word

```
var string = "but boys run fast boys are strong";

var strArray= string.split(" ");

var unique = [];
 for(var i =0; i< strArray.length; i++)
 {
   eval(unique[strArray] = new Object()); 
 }
```

Comment: I can't see regex in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrence of each matched word

```
var str = "but boys run fast boys are strong";
var matches = str.split(/\s/);
var res = matches.map(function(match) {
            return str.match(new RegExp(match, "g")).length;
          });

var bool = res.some(function(len) {return len > 1}));

console.log(bool);

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  if (res[i] > 1) console.log(matches[i], i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what word you're testing for duplicates you could use regular expressions like this `str.match(/boys/g).length > 1` to test if that word shows up more than once (assuming your string is in the `str` variable).

Answer (score 0):

Hello, here it is:

```
var temp = "but boys run fast boys are strong";
var count = (temp.match(/boys/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

I hope I have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Hello!

Here's an example with the exact answer you need:

```
var keyword = "boys"
var temp = "but boys run fast boys are strong";
var regex = new RegExp(keyword, "g");
var count = (temp.match(regex) || []).length;

if (count > 0) {
    console.log("true, since there are " + count + " repeats of the word '" + keyword + "'");
} else {
    console.log("false, not found.");
}
```

I hope I have helped!